# Redirect to another URL without losing the values that were passed on the header

Tags: css, url, redirect, http-headers, response.write

I just want to ask if there is a way to redirect to another url without losing the values that were passed on the header?

I tried using:

```
Response.Write(x); //x is the content
```

but the url does not change to the target url so the display is not the way it should look ike since the CSS file for that is also not called.

Comment: You can pass those values as query strings to the redirecting url.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make that part clear. I can't use query strings for security purposes. :)

Comment: How about cookies then?

Comment: Only headers since the code is already finished and i just need to test it by passing headers to the other site.

Comment: what do you mean by headers? do you want to use a template between two pages?

Comment: For example i have Site1 and Site2.
I don't have access to Site2 but to support Single Sign On(SSO), they added a function that will check the values of the header, if it contains the employee id, then it will do the log in automatically. I am doing Site1 to test if the SSO is doing it correctly. My task is to pass a header that contains the employee id. :)